# Bad interaction between Zope2 XML-RPC and AT Image mutator?

Tags: plone, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, transmogrifier

I am creating a [demo for mr.migrator](https://github.com/aclark4life/mr_migrator_demo) and have run in to an annoying problem, [showcased here](https://github.com/aclark4life/xmlrpc_setimage_wtf):

```
# create image
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url) # reset
data = open('screenshot.png').read()
try:
    proxy.invokeFactory('Image', 'screenshot.png')
except xmlrpclib.ProtocolError:
    print sys.exc_info()[1]
except xmlrpclib.Fault:
    print "The id is invalid - it is already in use." # most likely
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url + '/screenshot.png')
proxy.setTitle('This is an image')
try:
    proxy.setImage(data) # XXX this fails
except:
    print sys.exc_info()[1]
```

This code should populate the image field with data from the image, but instead it fails consistently with:

```
<ProtocolError for admin:admin@localhost:8080/Plone/screenshot.png: 500 Internal Server Error>
```

Worse, this is all Zope2 says. I don't see any tracebacks or anything else that indicates a problem when running Plone in the foreground.

What's my next step? You can check out and reproduce this here:

- https://github.com/aclark4life/xmlrpc_setimage_wtf

I would do this the "normal" way, with keyword arguments passed to invokeFactory, but [XML-RPC does not support them](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/ObjectPublishing.html#xml-rpc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a special character error. The xml-rpc protocol can use any character XML allows you to use. You should try to wrap the image data in a Binary wrapper:

```
wrappedData = xmlrpclib.Binary(open('screenshot.png').read())
```

More info:

- http://effbot.org/zone/xmlrpc-ascii.htm
- http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html

Comment: Progress, now I get: TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <xmlrpclib.Binary instance at 0x111246440>, <InterfaceClass plone.app.blob.interfaces.IBlobbable>) which I suspect I can work around by "marking" xmlrpclib.Binary or using another binary wrapper that blobs support?

Comment: I guess you could add an adapter from xmlrpclib.Binary to IBlobbable taking as example the one from StringIO to IBlobbable (http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.blob/trunk/src/plone/app/blob/adapters/stringio.py)

Comment: Done: https://github.com/aclark4life/plone.app.blob/blob/master/src/plone/app/blob/adapters/xmlrpc.py

Comment: Wow...I was just thinking "ehi this should be added to the p.a.blob package because it could be usefull also for others". Very Good :)